# How to make a non-numeric while loop repeat 1 additional time

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a sudoku-like solver; each pass through cullLists checks each list of possible values for each square against its row and column.  My problem is that it doesn't print the final version of the puzzle when solution = temp.  I could just put a print loop outside the while, but for the sake of learning I want to present it with the same print loop.

this is the cycle it runs

```
[1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 0]
[2, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
[6, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1]

[1, 5, [2, 3, 6], [2, 3, 6], 4, [2]]
[2, 4, [1, 3], [1, 3], 5, 6]
[4, [1, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 6], 3]
[[3, 5], [1, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 6], 4]
[6, 3, [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 5], 2, [5]]
[[5], 2, [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], 3, 1]

[1, 5, [3, 6], [3, 6], 4, 2]
[2, 4, [1, 3], [1, 3], 5, 6]
[4, [1, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 6], 3]
[[3], [1, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 6], 4]
[6, 3, [1, 4], [1, 4], 2, 5]
[5, 2, [4, 6], [4, 6], 3, 1]
```

I would like it to run one more cycle to print the list with solution[0,3] as 3 instead of [3]

```
temp = []
while solution != temp:
    temp = solution
    solution = cullLists(solution)
    for i in range (0, d):
        print(solution[i])
    print()
```

EDIT: I realized much later that the issue wasn't with the while loop, but with deep/shallow copy; temp = solution is not what I needed, but `temp = copy.deepcopy(solution)` with the `import copy` header solved it without altering the loop.

```
temp = []
while solution != temp:
    temp = copy.deepcopy(solution)
    solution = cullLists(solution)
    for i in range (0, d):
        print(solution[i])
    print()
```

Comment: Not sure I see the problem. As written, your code *will* run through the `print` section once even after `solution=cullLists(solution)` produces a result identical to `temp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling it from the outside of the while loop using a function is probably the correct way. If you do not want to do that however and insist on doing it within the loop, this will work.

```
temp = []
done = False

while not done:
    if temp != solution:
        temp = solution
        solution = cullLists(solution)
    else:
        done = True
    for i in range (0, d):
        print(solution[i])
    print()
```

Comment: Hi @Kebtiz, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should move your print statements to a function, and then call that function from both inside the loop and outside it.

Comment: If you want it to be part of the same logical construct, you can use a `while...else` loop, but those are a little esoteric.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the sort of reason that the `do`...`while` loop was created in the `C` language—it's a loop that is guaranteed to run at least once, and which checks whether to run again at the *end* rather than the beginning.  There's no such construct native to Python, but an equivalent pattern is:

```
while True:
    # do things
    # print things
    if solution == temp: break
```

However your code, as written in the question, will actually do the same, provided the loop runs at least once (whether or not it will always run once is unclear, because it's unclear what the initial value of `solution` is).